# Joins and restrictions for different columns at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

Can we use a join operation and make restrictions for different columns at the same time? I want to create a table on a Database (called DB1 in the example) based on three tables from another database (called DB2 in the example) where some columns in the new table filled with entrys when there´s a specific entry in an other column (in the example a"4" in column "attributeID" at table 2 indicates an entry in column "gender", a "5" indicates an entry in column "age"; a"7" in column "attributeID"at table 3 indicates an entry in column "street"). -> If yes, then how to do ?

Both databases are on the same server and DBMS is the same. ID1 and ID2 based on table1 in DB2; ID2, attributeID and value (where the gender or age is written depending on entry in attributeID) based on table2 in DB2; ID2 attributeID and value (where the street is written when the entry in the attributeID is a 7)based on table3 in DB2 .

Sample Data:

Table 1:

```
ID1      ID2
1        2
2        4
3        5
```

Table 2:

```
ID2    attributeID    value
2      3              Kahtrin ->an example entry which is not relevant
2      4              miss
2      5              22
4      1              active  ->an example entry which is not relevant
4      4              EMPTY/NULL
4      5              47
5      4              mr
5      5              34
5      6              Hindu ->an example entry which is not relevant
```

Table 3

```
 ID2    attributeID    value
2      5              20% ->an example entry which is not relevant
2      7              middlestreet 40
4      4              chinese ->an example entry which is not relevant
4      7              churchstreet 12
5      3              3Euro
5      7              EMPTY/NULL
```

Expected Outcome

Table 4:

```
ID1    ID2    gender    age     street
1      2      miss      22      middlestreet 40
2      4                47      churchstreet 12
3      5      mr        34
```

Here´s what I tried out (Made from point of view that I´m using DB1):

```
INSERT INTO table4 
        (id1, 
         id2, 
         gender,
         age,
         street) 
SELECT t1.id1, 
   t1.id2, 
   t2.value
   t2.value
   t3.value
FROM db1.table1 t1 
   LEFT JOIN db1.table2 t2 
          ON t1.ID2=t2.ID2 
             AND value = 4 OR 5
   LEFT JOIN db1.table3 t3 
          ON t1.ID2=t3.ID2 
             AND value = 7;
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why are you asking similar questions over and over again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972398/join-operation-and-restrictions-at-the-same-time, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955764/create-table-on-database-based-on-joins-on-other-database-same-server

Comment: I thought it´s better to start a new question for every new part -> I think this makes it clearer (easy to follow). Sorry if this was not right :/

Comment: So you are working with key-value tables. You should avoid them whereever possible, because they are difficult to maintain. How for example would you ensure that each person has at least a name? With a person table and columns name, age, etc., you would simply make name not nullable. Is there any specific reason to store the attributes in key-value pairs?

Comment: BTW: I think it was right to make this a separate question. The other question was about whether top put criteria in `ON` or `WHERE`, this one is about how to join different attributes from a key-value table.

Comment: Yes- but the data (tables etc.) exists in this way and I cannot change the structure (atm): can you plz help me anyway?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner: What more is there to help with? scaisEdge has already given you the answer: you must join tables 2 and 3 once for each attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You select is wrong  (don't produce the expected result ) you should  use two time the table t2 using an alias
and you should explicit assign the table t3 to value

```
SELECT t1.id1, 
   t1.id2, 
   t2.value
   t4.value
   t3.value
FROM db1.table1 t1 
   LEFT JOIN db1.table2 t2 
          ON t1.ID2=t2.ID2 
             AND value = 4 
   LEFT JOIN db1.table2 t4 
          ON t1.ID2=t4.ID2 
             AND value = 5             
   LEFT JOIN db1.table3 t3 
          ON t1.ID2=t3.ID2 
             AND t3.value = 7;
```